# How to prevent vb.net app from blocking the windows source folder thread for future D&D ops

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, drag-and-drop, thread-safety

I have a vb.net app which allows the drag & drop of a file into it for processing. The processing can be lengthy, but does not demand the extra work of a fully-threaded application.

Two instances of my app are run on the desktop at once to allow dragging a file into each app instance. The files to be dragged are visible in a folder on the windows file explorer form. The first drag & drop of file1 into the first instance of my app behaves as expected, and begins processing. However, when I attempt to drag file2 from the desktop file explorer into the second instance of the app, the source file explorer window does not allow any selection or pickup of the second file--presenting a cursor that seems to indicate that the drop has not taken place or that it is waiting for the original first drag & drop to complete.

My drag & drop code is very straightforward

```
Private Sub Form_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragEnter
  e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
End Sub
           
Private Sub Form_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
  Dim Complete_PathFilenames() As String = e.Data.GetData("FileDrop", False)
  For Each ThisScriptFile As String In Complete_PathFilenames
    PerformMyLongRunningProcess(ThisScriptFile)
  Next
End Sub
```

Short of launching my PerformMyLongRunningProcess() method as a new thread or process, is there a way to get the dropped file in my app, then immediately release the "grip" that my app seems to have on the windows desktop explorer window/file so that I can continue to drop source files into other instances (or even continue to use that desktop file explorer window)?

Comment: You might add explicit yield points within `PerformMyLongRunningProcess`, but it would probably be more appropriate to do something that ends up running it on another thread (either explicitly or implicitly through the task system e.g. `Task.Run`).

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say you've got two instances of your app running.  Is that two copies of the same executable running, or two separate form instances executed within the same instance of the executable?  I ask because if it is in fact two instances of the executable, effectively they are already running in separate threads, so what's happing in one shouldn't really impact the other unless you've gone out of your way to make it so.

Comment: @ Hurley: Two instances, meaning two copies of the same executable running at once. That’s what makes this so surprising—that the first running instance is somehow ‘tying up’ the desktop from the unfinished drag and drop op until that process is completed.